Unable to Build using Unreal Automation tool fro android
I am trying to assemble some automation for a mobile project using Unreal Automation tools, so far i have been trying some XML scripting using Buildgraph and some tools provided by Unreal engine.
When i try to use this script for Win64 Target it worked correctly , but when i am trying it for Android i got errors that i am struggling to figure out the root cause:
.\RunUAT.bat BuildGraph -script="D:\UE\TestAndroid\Build\TestAndroidBuild_B.xml" -Target="BuildAndTest TestAndroid"
<-/1>                                                                                   <History(1)>
Running AutomationTool...
Using bundled DotNet SDK version: 6.0.302
Starting AutomationTool...
Parsing command line: BuildGraph -script=D:\UE\TestAndroid\Build\TestAndroidBuild_B.xml -Target="BuildAndTest TestAndroid"
Initializing script modules...
Total script module initialization time: 0.54 s.
Using C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
Executing commands...
****** [1/4] TestAndroid Update Version Files Android

Saving file list to D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Saved\BuildGraph\TestAndroid Update Version Files Android\Tag-TestAndroid Update Version Files Android.xml

****** [2/4] TestAndroid Compile Tools Android

Reading local file list from D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Saved\BuildGraph\TestAndroid Update Version Files Android\Tag-TestAndroid Update Version Files Android.xml
Running: D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Binaries\ThirdParty\DotNet\6.0.302\windows\dotnet.exe "D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" -Target="ShaderCompileWorker Android Development -Manifest=D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Manifest-1-ShaderCompileWorker-Android-Development.xml" -Target="ZenLaunch Android Development -Manifest=D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Manifest-2-ZenLaunch-Android-Development.xml" -Target="UnrealPak Android Development -Manifest=D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Manifest-3-UnrealPak-Android-Development.xml" -Target="CrashReportClient Android Shipping -Manifest=D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Manifest-4-CrashReportClient-Android-Shipping.xml" -Target="CrashReportClientEditor Android Shipping -Manifest=D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Manifest-5-CrashReportClientEditor-Android-Shipping.xml" -log="D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Programs\AutomationTool\Saved\Logs\UBA-ShaderCompileWorker-Android-Development.txt"
Log file: D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Programs\AutomationTool\Saved\Logs\UBA-ShaderCompileWorker-Android-Development.txt
Creating makefile for ShaderCompileWorker (no existing makefile)
Total execution time: 0.93 seconds
Unhandled exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Text.ValueStringBuilder.ThrowFormatError()
   at System.Text.ValueStringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.Format(String format, Object arg0, Object arg1)
   at UnrealBuildTool.RulesAssembly.CreateTargetRulesInstance(String TypeName, TargetInfo TargetInfo, ILogger Logger, Boolean IsTestTarget, Boolean bSkipValidation) in D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\System\RulesAssembly.cs:line 0
   at UnrealBuildTool.RulesAssembly.CreateTargetRules(String TargetName, UnrealTargetPlatform Platform, UnrealTargetConfiguration Configuration, UnrealArchitectures Architectures, FileReference ProjectFile, CommandLineArguments Arguments, ILogger Logger, Boolean IsTestTarget, Boolean bSkipValidation, UnrealIntermediateEnvironment IntermediateEnvironment) in D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\System\RulesAssembly.cs:line 848
   at UnrealBuildTool.UEBuildTarget.Create(TargetDescriptor Descriptor, Boolean bSkipRulesCompile, Boolean bForceRulesCompile, Boolean bUsePrecompiled, UnrealIntermediateEnvironment IntermediateEnvironment, ILogger Logger) in D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Configuration\UEBuildTarget.cs:line 1281
   at UnrealBuildTool.UEBuildTarget.Create(TargetDescriptor Descriptor, BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, ILogger Logger) in D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Configuration\UEBuildTarget.cs:line 1226
   at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.CreateMakefileAsync(BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, TargetDescriptor TargetDescriptor, ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet, ILogger Logger) in D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Modes\BuildMode.cs:line 1114
   at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.BuildAsync(List`1 TargetDescriptors, BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet, BuildOptions Options, FileReference WriteOutdatedActionsFile, ILogger Logger, Boolean bSkipPreBuildTargets) in D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Modes\BuildMode.cs:line 396
   at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.ExecuteAsync(CommandLineArguments Arguments, ILogger Logger) in D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Modes\BuildMode.cs:line 252
   at UnrealBuildTool.UnrealBuildTool.Main(String[] ArgumentsArray) in D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.cs:line 660
Took 1,09s to run dotnet.exe, ExitCode=6
UnrealBuildTool failed. See log for more details. (D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Programs\AutomationTool\Saved\Logs\UBA-ShaderCompileWorker-Android-Development.txt)
AutomationTool executed for 0h 0m 3s
AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=6 (6)
BUILD FAILED

This is the xml i am using
<BuildGraph xmlns="http://www.epicgames.com/BuildGraph">

<!-- Project Info-->
<Property Name="ProjectName" Value="TestAndroid"/>
<Property Name="ProjectPath" Value="D:\UE\TestAndroid"/>
<Property Name="TargetName" Value="TestAndroid"/>

<Property Name="WithBATDefaults" Value="false"/>

<!-- Set Defaults for people running this script with no arguments-->
<Property Name="DefaultEditorPlatforms" Value="Android" />
<Property Name="DefaultTargetPlatform" Value= "Android" />
<Property Name="DefaultTargetConfigurations" Value= "Development" />



<Include Script="D:\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Build\Graph\Tasks\BuildAndTestProject.xml" />

</BuildGraph>

I have already tried rebuilding the project from Editor (which works for android correctly, Build package etc), checking the Config files which seem good and looking at some of the lines mentioned on the error but i am still unaware of the root cause.
If anyone has encountered a similar issue i will appreciate it
Thanks in advance for the answer
